# Google map route directions path color change with navigator moving on from one waypoint to another waypoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have requirement like

```
Source,
waypoint 1,
waypoint 2,
waypoint 3,
Destination
```

I need the path of `Source` to `waypoint 1` is one color, `waypoint 1` to `waypoint 2` is another color..respectively.

Here i am getting entire path is displayed in single(red)color.But I need to change the different color when we move to next waypoint

```
  mapSite.getDirection = function(latitudeValue, longitudeValue, waypts) {

        document.getElementById('directionsPanel').innerHTML = "";
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "red"
        }
    });
        var site = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: site,
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        mapSite.map = map;

            directionsDisplay.setMap(mapSite.map);
            var start = mapSite.latitude + "," + mapSite.longitude;                             
            var end = latitudeValue + "," + longitudeValue;

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                   var route = response.routes[0];
                   directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

                } 
           });
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is to call the direction api for multiple times. For example, Source->waypoint 1, waypoint 1->waypoint 2, waypoint 2->waypoint 3, waypoint 3->Destination...

Otherwise, the `response` you get from the callback function `directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {`, included `legs` with `steps` with polyline. You can draw the route out yourself rather than calling `directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);`

Refer to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs) for more information in the respond format.

Comment: Is there any possibility to change the `navigator color` with the direction path ?